# How to find nth derivative of a function using leibnitz rule in wxMaxima?

Tags: maxima

I know the pseudo code.

It goes something like this:

if f(x): g(x)*h(x) then u:g(x) and v:h(x)

for i:0 thru n do block
                   ( binomial(n,i)*diff(u,x,i)*diff(v,x,n-i), i:i+1);

I'm not able to actually execute the code. I get some thing I don't need. Please 
help me.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
kill(all)$

y:x^4*log(x);

u:log(x);

v:x^4;

n:4;

lsum(binomial(n,i)*diff(u,x,n-i)*diff(v,x,i),i,[0,1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: The sentence "enter code here " is not a part of the program